# EfonVNC (Real VNC based program for Windows CE) default password

Tags: vnc, windows-ce

I am using EfonVNC on a Windows CE device and everything works fine (so far). After a cold boot all settings are reverted and so the password is lost.

Does anybody know the standard password for EfonVNC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've helped myself by exporting the keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/RealVNC into the startup directory once I've set the password once.

Now the password is set to this password after every cold boot.

Answer (score 2):

(winec7)

Inside `osdesign.reg` Put following lines:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\RealVNC\WinVNC4]
"QueryOnlyIfLoggedOn"=dword:00000000
"QueryConnect"=dword:00000000
"ReverseSecurityTypes"="None"
"SecurityTypes"="VncAuth"
"Password"=hex:49,40,15,F9,A3,5E,8B,22`

In WINCE startup put the file `winvnc.exe` from remote computers VNC Viewer open using password of "123456"